# Should we use sessions instead of bearer tokens with OpenID Connect server-side authorization code flows?

Tags: security, oauth2, spring-boot, angular, openid

I want to build an app with a SPA (Angular) frontend and a REST API (Spring Boot) backend.
I want a modern account system for this app: users log in through OpenID Connect, using either a social login like Facebook or Google or a custom account with us (achieved through the use of an OAuth authorization server like Keycloak deployed alongside the application).

I see two possible ways of achieving this: the SPA/client-side authorization code flow with PKCE or the REST API/server-side traditional authorization code flow. The latter seems like the most secure approach and is supported by Spring Boot's OpenID client library.

However, when using Spring Boot's client library, when the authentication is complete I notice that Spring starts a traditional session. I have the feeling that in modern web applications using stateless bearer token authorization headers is recommended. While traditional sessions can also be very secure and scalable, using bearer tokens does seem much more easy to maintain.

My question is then simply: are Spring Boot's OpenID client's defaults actually sensible? Should I override them and use bearer tokens with my client web app instead of sessions (using HTTP-only cookies or some other mechanism for my SPA to remember the authentication token and emulate sessions securely), should I stick to Spring Boot's strategy of using sessions or should I do something else entirely?

To me Spring Boot's defaults mainly make sense considering traditional Java EE or Spring landscapes, or to easen the migration to OpenID Connect. But I could be wrong. I'd really appreciate your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: A server-side session is good for more than authentication. In the .NET tech stack, even *unauthenticated* users have a session. This could be done for tracking purposes, preferences that live only during a session, or any other simple data you want to access repeatedly on the server or the client.